# Telegram: Use directives of angularJS [Tampermonkey]

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, userscripts, telegram, tampermonkey

I am trying to change/advance the design of the telegram web app (https://web.telegram.org).

For my needs, the emoji/sticker section is simply to small and I want to make a new div box for it and probably add a search-option for it via a tampermonkey userscript.

My problem is, that I am not into AngularJS and I am struggling with the code. I found already the part in the code of the app, but I wonder how I can access it. The important part starts here: [Sticker Directive](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/blob/125153f7672488b7b721455c9496368a7a8300c6/app/js/directives.js#L2089)

What I already achieved:

- Get all categories of stickers and their stickers with their ID
- create a new box where all of them are listed as in my preferred design

*Preview* [image]

(The images on the very right are only shown, because I used an own technique to get images. Unfortunately, this works only when the sticker was already seen by the client in a received/sent message)

What I am missing:

- get the location of the images for the src-attribute
- add click listener to the images to add them in message
- preferred: just copying the behavior of the standard-sticker box

The problem here is, that the app is loading the images only when they're visible in the preview container of the standard-sticker box.

When they are not visible, there is only the link without the image, like this:

`<a class="composer_sticker_btn" data-sticker="677815138606121208"></a>`

When the sticker is scrolled into the preview, it becomes like this:

```
<a class="composer_sticker_btn" data-sticker="677815138606121208" my-load-sticker="" document="document" thumb="true" img-class="composer_sticker_image">
    <img class="composer_sticker_image" alt="[ Sticker]" src="filesystem:https://web.telegram.org/temporary/225538627_21169_7021113544866120056.webp">
</a>
```

The directive, which is doing this, is written here [Sticker Directive](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/blob/125153f7672488b7b721455c9496368a7a8300c6/app/js/directives.js#L2089).

**So...TL;DR**

I want to rearrange the stickers from the standard-sticker box to a new, custom one. How can I copy the behavior (loading images/adding click listeners) of the standard box to my custom one? I guess it would be the easiest way.

If that is not possible: How can I execute the functions from the angularJS directives via a userscript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is either good or too broad. I gave you the BOD since I'm not fluent in Angular.   I strongly suspect that you can't call the `myLoadSticker` directive because there is probably not a hook provide for it.  And signing up for telegram, to check, is not gonna happen. ... ... You may be able to just send scroll events to the "standard-sticker box" before you scrape for images.  Also, explore the methods of the `window` object.  Maybe the angular library was nice enough to leave a hook...